# Ansible: Limit a task in a playbook to localhost

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to restrict an Ansible play to a specific host
Here's a cut down version of what I want:

```
 - hosts some_host_group
 tasks:

- name: Remove existing server files
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  file:
    dest: /tmp/test_file
    state: present

- name: DO some other stuff
  file: 
      ...
```

I want to (as an early task), remove a *local* directory (I've created a file in the example as it's a more easily observed test).   I was under the impression that I could limit a play to a set of hosts with the "hosts" parameter to the task -
but I get this error:

```
ERROR! 'hosts' is not a valid attribute for a Task

 $ansible --version
 ansible 2.3.1.0
```

Thanks.

PS I could wrap the ansible in a shell fragment, but that's ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`delegate_to` or `local_action`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) and tell Ansible to [run the task only once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) (otherwise it will try to delete the directory as many times as target hosts in your play, although it won't be a problem).

<sup>You should also use `absent` not `present` if you want to remove directory, as you stated.</sup>

```
- name: Remove existing server files
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
  file:
    dest: /tmp/test_file
    state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your playbook, have a look at [Ansible Intro](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html), [Local Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) and [Delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

```
- hosts: some_host_group
  tasks:
    - name: Remove existing server files

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - file:
      dest: /tmp/test_file
      state: present 
    - name: DO some other stuff
      file:
```

Comment: I know there is an error - I mentioned it in the question.  I like the approach you have described with multiple hosts sections, but this doesn't seem to work.